# Trying to construct a Bash executable string involving MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I am trying to write a Bash script to run a MySQL query from a string constructed in the script. I have been able to construct the query string, and it looks correct when echo'd. And I can cut and paste it into the shell command line and it runs. But, I need to basically cut the query results to just the words, OK or CRITICAL. Nothing else. When I try to save the query result to a bash variable I get:

mysql: unknown option '-2'

If I cut out the grep and cut code, I get the `mysql --help` results. So, it's not liking my mysql string, but I don't know why. Help?

BTW- Running CentOS 6.3

```
alert=`mysql myDB -e "select value from config_table where name=\"ach_alert_time\"\G" | /bin/grep value: | /bin/cut -f2 -d:`
echo $alert  #Brings back 18,50,00

sql="mysql myDB -e 'select if(count(*) > 0,\"CRITICAL\",\"OK\") as STATUS from xyz_batch where timestamp > concat(date(now()),\" \",maketime("$alert"))\G' | /bin/grep OK  | /bin/cut -f2 -d:"
echo $sql # mysql myDB -e 'select if(count(*) > 0,"CRITICAL","OK") as STATUS from xyz_batch where timestamp > concat(date(now())," ",maketime( 18,50,00))\G' | /bin/grep OK | /bin/cut -f2 -d

status=`$sql`

# Whoops!
# mysql: unknown option '-2'

echo $status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you run `$sql` as a command, it under goes word-splitting, filename expansion, and so on, with no respect for any quotation-marks that `$sql` might contain. And it *won't* handle pipes and other shell metacharacters. For example, if you're in a directory that contains the files `foo` and `bar`, then this:

```
cmd="echo '     *     ' | grep baz"
$cmd
```

will print `' bar foo ' | grep baz` — it won't preserve whitespace, it will expand the `*` into a list of files, and it will treat `|` and `grep` as arguments to `echo`.

You can work around this by using the command `eval "$sql"` instead of just `$sql`:

```
status=`eval "$sql"`
```

but you *may* want to re-evaluate your design a bit. Maybe there's a better way to achieve what you want?

---

**Edited to add:** You say that you're constructing the query in the script, but do you actually need to store the entire command in a variable? Something like this:

```
sql="select if(count(*) > 0,\"CRITICAL\",\"OK\") as STATUS from xyz_batch where timestamp > concat(date(now()),\" \",maketime("$alert"))\G"
status=`mysql myDB -e "$sql" | /bin/grep OK  | /bin/cut -f2 -d:`
```

would not have this problem, since then `$sql` is then just a single argument, so you don't need Bash to do anything special with it.

Comment: Looks to me like a quoting problem.  Make sure your use of backticks and quotes is what you intended.  Assigning variables the result value of a backtick command might be causing some confusion as well.  Break that up and it will be easier to debug.

Comment: @djangofan: No, not really; it's a running-a-variable-that-contains-a-command-is-not-the-same-as-running-the-command-directly problem. :-P

Answer (score 1):

You can drive yourself crazy trying to get every last thing properly escaped. Break it into manageable steps:

```
# Multiple lines allowed, for readability. Inside single quotes, no
# escaping needed.
sql_template='select if (count(*) > 0, "CRITICAL", "OK") as STATUS
  from xyz_batch
  where timestamp > concat( date( now() ), " ", maketime("%s"))\G'

# Bash 4 only
printf -v sql_stmt "$sql_template" "$alert"
# Bash 3 equivalent
# sql_stmt=$( printf "$sql_template" "$alert" )

status=$( mysql myDB -e "$sql_stmt" | awk -F: '/OK/ {print $2}' )
```

Comment: -1, sorry. This has the exact same problems as the OP's original code: it will perform word-splitting and filename-expansion on the contents of `$sql_pipeline`, and it will pass `|`, `awk`, and so on as arguments to `mysql`.

Comment: (In other words: the OP's problem isn't really an issue of escaping; or rather -- treating it as an issue of escaping *is* a surefire way to drive yourself crazy.)

Comment: True. I debated whether to preserve that aspect of the code; I'm going to save myself the trouble and just recommend writing the pipeline out.

Comment: Which is the same thing I recommended. :-)

Comment: Yeah, you modified your answer while I was writing mine up. Overlap! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with double code.

```
sql="mysql myDB -e 'select if(count(*) > 0,\"CRITICAL\",\"OK\") as STATUS from xyz_batch where timestamp > concat(date(now()),\" \",maketime("$alert"))\G' | /bin/grep OK  | /bin/cut -f2 -d:"
```

Replace with

```
sql=`mysql myDB -e 'select if(count(*) > 0,\"CRITICAL\",\"OK\") as STATUS from xyz_batch where timestamp > concat(date(now()),\" \",maketime("$alert"))\G' | /bin/grep OK  | /bin/cut -f2 -d:`
```

Comment: Tips: sh -x scriptname to debug shell script.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the OP is trying to do. In the actual script, the variable `$sql` is constructed programmatically, so what you describe is not an option.

Comment: No, he's not. He's storing the *command* in `$sql`. The *output* goes into `$status`.

Comment: In my solution he can use status=$sql

Comment: Satish: But your solution isn't a solution. He has this variable, `$sql`, that's he's constructed using a script. He needs to run the contents of the variable as a command, and capture the output. Your "solution" is simply not to construct the variable to begin with, but rather, to have hard-coded the command into the script. That doesn't accomplish what he needs.